Light or heavy string gauge for alternate picking?
I am learning a high-tempo linear piece involving alternate picking and string skipping on an electro-acoustic guitar. There are no string bends involved. The piece is challenging, and I'm wondering if I might benefit from a change to either a lighter or a heavier string gauge. Is there consensus on the choice of a light or heavy string gauge when playing in such a manner?
The string action is currently quite low, and some fret positions buzz a little. I believe that the truss rod may need adjustment with a change either way (to maintain the current low action). I'm prepared to visit my local luthier again to set things up if that's the way to go.
I am currently using a set of D'Addario 80/20 Bronze 11-52 gauge strings. Tuning is standard EADGBE, and the pick is a Jim Dunlop Jazz III.

Sometimes, when I use an acoustic guitar unamplified, I'll tremolo pick, for volume and sustain. My strings are very light as in .008s. That works well for me. Maybe it's more of a personal preference

Tuning is EADGBE and the pick is a Jim Dunlop Jazz III. I'll add it to the question.

Actually you can try that out for yourself. Heavy strings will have higher tension, which means they will take less movement to slip off the picks, but they will take more force at the same movement. But the string will naturally be softer in the center and harder at the ends. So you can try playing closer to the bridge or closer to the neck to see if it would be easier with heavier or lighter strings.
Nevertheless what’s more important is technique. The strings might help with masking certain problems with technique (if you use far too much pick hard strings might be harder, else light should be a bit harder). But it is better to develop the required technique.
Playing fast is almost always a matter of avoiding unnecessary movement (and using all of your muscles efficiently). To minimize movement try not to dig too much into the strings. Try to pick only with the very tip of a not too soft pick. Also sometimes when we try to do certain countermotions we can tense up and loose speed. So maybe it helps to try to think of the alternate pick not as two picking motions, but as single picks at half speed, and then you just trigger an action at the returning motion (so a double action similar to double tonguing or double strokes). Then you can try to warm up using say 4 8ths downpicked and 4 8ths with double picking (so 8 16ths, but stay in the motion of the 8ths and simply add a pick at the returning motion).
With proper technique you should be able to go pretty fast on both light and heavy strings.

There is no general consensus on this. Speaking generally, both jazz players with high action and heavy strings and contemporary players with low action and thin strings are capable of playing single lines with great speed. Pick shape, type and thickness will also vary among both styles. What you choose should be more a question of style and personal preference than: “Are thinner or thicker strings faster?”
Since your strings are on the light side for a steel string acoustic and strings are not expensive you could experiment with a heavier gauge to see if you notice any benefit. A heavier set will also probably solve your buzzing problem without a truss rod adjustment since there will be more tension on the neck, which will translate into more relief on the fingerboard.
The bottom line is unless someone is using multiple instruments with different setups, guitarists have to make a choice on their setup which will give them a comfortable feel and good tone for everything they are going to be doing on their instruments, not just one specific thing. Experiment a bit if you like but in the end choose a setup that feels good to you and then focus on improving your technique.

Thanks. I am reading in all the answers that there is no consensus. I also note that you group players as either: high action and heavy strings or; low action and light strings. Is that just as an example of contrast? Or do you think these two are more common (than high action and light strings or low action and heavy strings)?

@user643722 Yes, my point was simply to give you an example of contrast and that speed is possible with either. I probably should have used the words higher and lower instead. I do believe that those combinations are much more common than the inverse although most live somewhere in the middle. Someone with very light strings is more likely have lower action since they are going for an instrument that is easier to play. A player that uses heavy strings can also have low action if they choose but they tend to use them with higher action to draw more tone and volume out of their instruments.

I would intuit that heavier strings make this easier on your right hand, since they get displaced less when plucked, so they're less of a moving target.  I've certainly experienced this when playing fingerstyle bass.  However, there are other tradeoffs involved with going to heavier strings, such as the increased amount of work for your fretting hand, and there are plenty of technical players using much lighter strings than your current set.
I would not recommend heavier strings as a way to enhance your playing abilities, nor do I expect it would make a significant difference to your ability anyway.
